# Enviar notificación con Laravel

Tags: laravel, notificaciones

Hace poco empecé a aprender Laravel.

En este momento tengo hecho un pequeño sistema donde se guarda información varia.

Mi problema/duda surge porque los usuarios no se registran por sí solos, sino que los registra un administrador. Entonces, lo que hice es crear un controlador para poder manejar los usuarios.

En el controlador tengo el método "store" que sería para grabar en la base de datos la información de cada usuario.
Una vez que guardo los datos, lo que quiero es mandar una notificación por mail al nuevo usuario con sus datos, email y contraseña, para que pueda acceder al sistema.

La notificación la tengo creada, pero no logro comprender cómo aunar eso: que desde el método pueda llamar a la notificación para enviarla (añadiendo los datos correspondientes)...

Acá pego el código como lo tengo armado:

**Método Store**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request -> validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'dni' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'province' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $newUser = new App\User;

        $newUser -> name = $request -> name;
        $newUser -> lastname = $request -> lastname;
        $newUser -> dni = $request -> dni;
        $newUser -> phone = $request -> phone;
        $newUser -> address = $request -> address;
        $newUser -> city = $request -> city;
        $newUser -> province = $request -> province;
        $newUser -> zip = $request -> zip;
        $newUser -> password = Hash::make($request -> password);
        $newUser -> email = $request -> email;
        $newUser -> photo = '16';

        //Acá debería enviar la notificación

        $users = App\User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('users.list', compact('users'))->with('status', 'Los datos fueron guardados. Se envió un correo con la información.');
}
```

**Notificación**

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class UserWelcome extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $userName;
    protected $userPassword;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userName, $userPassword)
    {
        $this -> userName = $userName;
        $this -> userPassword = $userPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Activación de cuenta')
                    ->greeting('¡Hola!')
                    ->line('Hemos creado una cuenta para ti. Puedes ingresar ahora con los siguientes datos:')
                    ->line('Ususario: ' . $this -> userName . ' / Contraseña: ' . $this -> userPassword)
                    ->action('Acceder', url('/'))
                    ->line('¡Ya eres parte de nuestro equipo!')
                    ->salutation('Saludos.');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Alguna ayuda??

Comment: Te está faltando insertar en base de datos `$newUser->save();`. Luego envías la notificación con `$newUser->notify(new UserWelcome( $request->name, $request->password ));`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Muchas gracias! lo logré!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso lo que dice la documentación de Laravel:

### [Envío de notificaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#sending-notifications)

Las notificaciones pueden enviarse de dos maneras: usando el método `notify` del trait `Notifiable` o usando la facade `Notification`. Primero, exploremos usando el trait:

#### Usando el Trait Notifiable

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Este trait es utilizado de manera predeterminada por el modelo `App\User` y contiene un método que puede usarse para enviar notificaciones: `notify`. El método `notify` espera recibir una instancia de notificación:

```
use App\Notifications\InvoicePaid;

$user->notify(new UserWelcome($request->name, $request->password));
```

*Nota:* Recuerda, puedes usar el trait `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` en cualquiera de tus modelos. No estás limitado a incluirlo solo en su modelo `User`.

#### Usando la Facade Notification

Alternativamente, puedes enviar notificaciones a través de la facade `Notification`. Esto es útil principalmente cuando necesitas enviar una notificación a varias entidades notificables, como una colección de usuarios. Para enviar notificaciones utilizando la facade, pasa todas las entidades notificables y la instancia de notificación al método `send`:

```
Notification::send($users, new UserWelcome($request->name, $request->password));
```